# Using COUNTIF in conjunction with ISNA to identify #N/A entries in an Excel cell range

Tags: excel

Consider the following column entry for `A1:A10`:

```
#N/A 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
#N/A
```

I want to write a statement that is equal to `TRUE` if it finds any #N/A entries in the range. Goal is to encode this into a conditional formatting call for use as a data quality check tool.

Any thoughts?

Cheers,

Aaron

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since the original answerer changed his post, I'll post my comment on his answer as an answer.

`=IF(COUNTIF(A:A,NA())>0, "TRUE","FALSE")`

Comment: Besides reading the question wrong, I also noticed there was an "excel-vba" tag. So I wasn't even sure if he wanted a formula.

Comment: Removed excel-vba tag to avoid confusion. You're correct that what's desired here is a formula. Will review these solutions on Monday and upvote the winner. Thanks all.

Comment: nailed it. great answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    =SUM(IF(ISNA(YOUR_DATA_RANGE),1,0))>0

entered as an array formula (CTRL-ENTER).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function: ERROR.TYPE(error_val)
when NA is equal to 7.

Reference: 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ERROR-TYPE-function-10958677-7c8d-44f7-ae77-b9a9ee6eefaa

and then put it in a sumif :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISERROR(A1:A10))>0
```

[Here](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-cells-that-contain-errors) is an explanation of the formula. It checks for any kind of error, however, not just #N/A (which might be a good thing).